# How to prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|{\sin{nx}\over x}\right|\,\mathrm dx\ge{2\over\pi} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac1k$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, inequality

How to prove $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|{\sin{nx}\over x}\right| \,\mathrm{d}x\ge{2\over\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}.$$

I have tried infinite series but absolute value and $n$ ruins it. Induction also didn't work very well.

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: change variables and split the interval of integration into $n$ parts.

Comment: @Wojowu did try that too. Didnt know how to proceed though. Mod was removed though

Comment: Is the name of the book ISI, TOMATO or subjective?

Comment: Book - ISI TOMATO, Section - Subjective, Q number- 161

Comment: Oh, Wojowu had (quite likely) the same idea. Deleting my comment.

Comment: Why do you have to mention the name of a book in a way as if everybody in the world is familiar with it? Either quote the full name of the book or don't mention it at all.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Tagging for easier google search. You live up to your name

Comment: @The inequality should be REVERSED.  Check into your book!

Comment: @RobertZ Yep, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This was the original question

Enforcing that change of variables $t=nx$ we get

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin{nx}}{x}\right|\,\mathrm dx
&= \int_{0}^{n\pi}\left|\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\right|\,\mathrm dt 
\\&=\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n-1} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\right|\,\mathrm dt
\\&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\,\mathrm dt +\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n-1} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\right|\,\mathrm dt
\\&\le \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\,\mathrm dt +\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k\pi} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\sin{t}\right|\,\mathrm dt
\\&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\,\mathrm dt +\frac{2}{\pi} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}$$

Given that $$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\sin{t}\right|\,\mathrm dt = 2~~$$

> By the same Token you obtain the reverse inequality, 
>   $$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin{nx}}{x}\right|\,\mathrm dx
> &=\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n-1} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\right|\,\mathrm dt
> \\&\ge  \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\sin{t}\right|\,\mathrm dt
> \\&= \frac{2}{\pi} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}
> =\frac{2}{\pi} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\end{align}$$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$ is not $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but $\text{Si}(\pi)>\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the answer to the actuall question is below that the OP changed the question after I posted the first one

Comment: The point is that you wrote $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt +\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} =\frac{\pi}{2} +\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$ but that is not true, it holds as a $\geq $.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks I got it you are right I removed it though

Comment: @ChoF sure you are right

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin n x}{x}\right|\,dx = \int_{0}^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin(z)|}{z}\,dz&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin z}{z+k\pi}\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(z)\left(\frac{1}{z+k\pi}+\frac{1}{\pi-z+k\pi}\right)\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(z)\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{(k+1/2)^2\pi^2-z^2}\,dz\\&\color{red}{\geq}&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\pi(k+1/2)}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(z)\,dz\\&=&\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1/2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and similarly
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin n x}{x}\right|\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin(z)|}{z}\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(z)\left(\frac{1}{z+k\pi}+\frac{1}{\pi-z+k\pi}\right)\,dz\\&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(z)\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{(k+1/2)^2\pi^2-z^2}\,dz\\&\color{red}{\leq}&\text{Si}(\pi)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(2k+1)}{k(k+1)}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(z)\,dz\\&=&\text{Si}(\pi)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
but in general the inequality $\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin n x}{x}\right|\,dx\leq \frac{2H_n}{\pi}$ **does not** hold. On the other hand $\frac{2H_n}{\pi}\leq \int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin n x}{x}\right|\,dx\leq \frac{20}{13}+\frac{2H_n}{\pi}$ **does** hold. This can be proved also by exploiting
$$ \left|\sin x\right|=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1}=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin^2(nx)}{4n^2-1} $$
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(|\sin x|\mathbb{1}_{(0,n\pi)}(x)\right)(s)=(1-e^{-\pi ns})\left[\frac{2}{\pi s}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{s}{(4m^2+s^2)(4m^2-1)}\right] $$
leading to the identity
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\right|\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-\pi ns}}{1+s^2}\coth\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\,ds. $$