# Finding lower bound of trigonometric intergation

Tags: integration

Prove
$$\int_0^{\pi}\left|{\sin nx\over x}\right|\,dx\ge\frac2\pi\left(1+\frac12+\frac13\dots+\frac1n\right)$$
I'm not sure how to start. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You have already asked [exactly the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647244/how-to-prove-that-int-0-pi-left-sinnx-over-x-right-mathrm-dx-ge2?noredirect=1&lq=1).